# Variable selectors in regression models

Tags: r, regression, modeling, tidymodels

I have a database with one `y` and 100 `x`, ordered by `x1` to `x100`.

I want a code to code:

```
ron_db %>%
lm(data = .,
   y ~ {x1 + x2 + ... + x100})
```

Comment: This actually work. If you want to answer, maybe you can describe the method for selecting only some columns. Should it be y ~ (. %>% select()) ???

Comment: `select` works on data frames, not within formulas. `ron_db %>% select(y, starts_with(x)) %>% lm(data = ., y ~ .)`